# The Adobe Flash Player Settings popup is appearing offscreen in my Flex4 app. How do I stop this?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4

I have a page with some html content and my Flex app in the bottom left hand corner. At one point, the Adobe Flash Player Settings popup appears, but for some reason I can only just see the top of it, the rest is off screen towards the bottom. Does anyone know how I can fix this so that the user can interact with the popup? Thanks for reading.

EDIT: Forgot to mention this. I set the height of the application in the opening application tag, to 240. The whole app is visible in the HTML page, but for some reason the background colour of the Flex app goes past its height and width properties. This is probably causing the Flash Player Settings popup problems right?

Answer (score 0):

Check you're stage align and scale mode.

In your creation complete handler or entry point, try something like:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

From what you're describing that should be the issue.

Comment: I put these lines into my init method, but no luck. Not sure if this matters, but I had to put them at the bottom of the method, because if they were at the top the rest of init code wasn't being run. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ben Ideally you would want to setup the stage as soon as possible. Try adding those in an event handler for Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, then stage would not be null. HTH